# Spring Boot - Accessing GCP bucket throws 403 error

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, bucket

I am trying to access a bucket from GCP bucket. It works perfectly when I run it from my local. But when I deploy the application in GCP Kubernetes and run the same function, it throws below error in the console. I am not sure how to resolve the issue. Can anyone please help me ?

```
E 2020-03-09T00:08:58.059173975Z {

E 2020-03-09T00:08:58.059192256Z   "code" : 403,

E 2020-03-09T00:08:58.059197666Z   "errors" : [ {

E 2020-03-09T00:08:58.059208250Z     "domain" : "global",

E 2020-03-09T00:08:58.059213845Z     "message" : "Request is prohibited by organization's policy. 
vpcServiceControlsUniqueIdentifier: b4bca9177b2c10bb",

E 2020-03-09T00:08:58.059219532Z     "reason" : "vpcServiceControls"

E 2020-03-09T00:08:58.059224892Z   } ],



            BillingCloudStorage bc = new BillingCloudStorage();
        InputStream is = bc.test();
        System.out.println("Input Stream is");
        System.out.println(is);
        options = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                    .setProjectId(PROJECT_ID)
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
                       is) ).build();
     System.out.println("Received the options");   
    Storage storage = options.getService();
    Blob blob = storage.get(BUCKET_NAME, OBJECT_NAME);
```

Comment: "Request is prohibited by organization's policy"- this pretty much says a lot. I suggest you look it up and do some more research on how Kubernetes work on GCP. Also, get some understanding of roles and authentication from your DevOps team. Once done all that, post some elaborate results and that would be more helpful in getting you an answer.

Comment: Hi Wildnez,

Please note that this is my own GCP project (Free trial) to learn how to read and write to bucket . I tried troubleshooting on my own using Google troubleshooting link
[link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/troubleshooting). It does not have clear solution. That's why I though of posting it here. I will also try to explore more on this subject and post here if i find anything relevant. Please note that I dont have any organization in my GCP console, I just have project because its trial version. I have posted the code on how I am connecting.Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, indeed, the VPC Service Controls from your GCP is configured in a way that it's not allowing your GKE to access the bucket from your Cloud Storage - as this part of your stacktrace indicates.

> "reason" : "vpcServiceControls"

As per the documentation [Determine if an error is due to VPC Service Controls](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/troubleshooting#determine_if_an_error_is_due_to), the error `403: Request violates VPC Service Controls.` is related to Cloud Storage, which seems to be what you are facing. The documentation [Known Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/supported-products#service-limitations) provides more insights on this VPC configuration needed for it to work

Besides that, you need to be sure that it's the same service account for both GKE and Cloud Storage configured are authorized, for them to be able to integrate between each other. This documentation - [Integrating microservices with Pub/Sub and GKE](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/integrating-microservices-with-pubsub) - should provide more information on how to integrate GCP microservices with GKE.

Let me know if the information helped you!